# PHP program responses are not sent to SSE

Tags: javascript, php

I've started using Server Sent Events technology but I'm having some problems. Before starting my project, I was wondering how to set up a simple SSE connection between the Server and the Client. Here is my code:
JS :

```
const eventSource = new EventSource("http://localhost/sse_test.php");
eventSource.onmessage = function( event ) {
    console.log( event.data ) ;
};
```

PHP :

```
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
while ( true ) {
    echo 'data:';
    $messages = time();
    $messages = json_encode( $messages );
    echo $messages;
    echo $a;
    echo "\n\n";
    $a++;
    flush();
    sleep(5); 
}
```

My goal in this code is to send every 5s the timestamp, so I start by `echo "data:"` then the content, and to finish by `echo "\n\n"` to mean sending my message to the client. But, in the developer console, I was getting something different. Instead of receiving the timestamp every 5s, I was receiving 5 to 10 timestamps with each 5s difference as requested. What is strange is that I receive the right result, but in a packet of several messages. The messages to the Client are not sent one by one. So I tried to see if I could make it work by sending the data one by one, but most of the time the program sends the data at the end of the maximum time that a PHP page can load, which is 120s in my php.ini.
[image]

Here we can see that my php file sent data only after 120s when it is supposed to send data every 5s.

[image]

And here are the data that I received after the 120s when I would have received them one by one.

I have the impression that the `echo "\n\n"` is useless because it doesn't do the job of indicating the end of the data and therefore sending it to the client.
Is there a solution? Or am I cursed to keep using HTTP

Comment: You can look into output buffering (see [ob_flush](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php) for some information on it), but most of the time PHP will not send any information to the browser or request until the script is completely done

Comment: First, try adding `ob_flush();` before the `flush();` call.